# why when i press "A" i go up but its supposed to go left?

Tags: java

```
//KeyHandler.java  
package Main;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener{
    public boolean upPressed, downPressed, leftPressed, rightPressed;
    
    
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    
     int code = e.getKeyCode ();
     
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            upPressed =true;
     }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            downPressed = true;
     }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            leftPressed = true;
     }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            rightPressed = true;
     }
  };
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    
      if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            upPressed = false;
      }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            downPressed = false;
      }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            leftPressed = false;
      }     
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
           rightPressed = false;
      }
   };
}

//GamePanel.java

public void update () {
        if (keyH.upPressed == true) {
            playery -= playerspeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.downPressed == true){
            playery += playerspeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.leftPressed == true){
            playery -= playerspeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.rightPressed == true) {
            playerx += playerspeed;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at your update, you see that `playery` is used 3 times and `playerx` once.

`leftPressed` should use `playerx` instead of `playery`. This kind of error is a good practice for debugging, since you know exactly when the error is happening (when pressing left). Since the rest is working correctly, all you need to do is check carefully what is happening in your `leftPressed` condition